# How do I upgrade ubuntu eglibc from 2.11 to 2.12?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, glibc

I m currently on Ubuntu 10.04

```
$ uname -a
Linux dpn2 2.6.32-27-server #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 02:05:21 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ldd --version
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.7) 2.11.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

I need to upgrade to EGLIBC 2.12.x. I can do this by doing a distro upgrade but is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Not in Ubuntu, no.  If you're willing to replace such a critical package, Linux From Scratch project might be a better idea.